What is Internal Potential Energy?
I'm reading Classical Mechanics by Goldstein. On Page no. 11, there's an equation derived for potential energy.
$$V = \sum_{i} V_i + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j;i\neq j} V_{i,j} 
$$
Goldstein says "The second term on the right in Eq. will be called the internal potential
energy of the system. In general, it need not be zero and, more important, it may
vary as the system changes with time."
So what is this internal potential energy? Why does everywhere I search, no info pops up regarding this ?

Please enclose your equations with $ signs to activate math mode.

The term is $V_{ij}$, not $V_iV_j$, and this is clearly explained in the lead-up to this equation. This is the potential energy associated with the forces exerted by particles in the system on other particles in the system. The $V_i$ are potential energies associated with forces exerted by particles outside the system on particles in the system.

So a good example of this is--let's make it maximally simple: frictionless pucks on level frictionless ice. You can then evolve their motion with lossless collision.
Now add some charge to the pucks, so $V_{ij} \ne 0$. You can still evolve their motion and keep track of the potential energy of the system.
Now we need a special idealized puck: It's two half pucks joined by a row of idealized spring with a clamp.
Now, when the pucks collides, the springs compress and are locked into place. Now, $V_i \ne 0$, since the puck-thing can store potential energy, that must be accounted for.
You could imagine the spring releases on the next collision, so it can go back to $V_{ij}$, and kinetic energy.
Ofc, some molecules are (somewhat) like that.
You can also make the surface curved, and if the gravitational potential energy of the puck is internal or not...may be up to you. I suppose I would make it external.

Okay, I understood that. But what my mind dives towards is Entropy. Entropy is sometimes defined as the measure of how much energy is not available to do work. To me this definition of Entropy & some essence of Internal Potential energy feels the same. So is there a relation between them or not ?

Consider a system of two charges $q_1$, $q_2$ in the region between a pair of plates producing an electric field. The total potential energy of the electrons is
$$
V = q_1 \phi_1 + q_2 \phi_2 + \frac{q_1 q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 |{\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2|}
$$
This has the form
$$
V = V_1 + V_2 + \frac{1}{2}(V_{12} + V_{21})
$$
where $V_1 = q_1 \phi_1$, $V_2 = q_2 \phi_2$ and $V_{12} = V_{21} = 
q_1 q_2 / {(4 \pi \epsilon_0 |{\bf r}_1-{\bf r}_2|)}$.
To get the idea more generally, I suggest you write down your own version for three particles, and then you will see the general pattern.
